# How to numerically sort files in linux with leading text in the name

Tags: linux

I am looking to run a script on hundreds of files with the naming convention:

```
hello.H    
hello.1
hello.2
...
hello.10
hello.11
...
hello.20
...
hello.100
hello.101
...
hello.200
```

The order in which the files are processed matters. I am using a for-loop that uses find/sort to run the script:

```
for i in `find ./ -name hello*.[0-9] | sort`; do ./myScript $i; done
```

Because of the leading text before the numerical portion of the filename, the order I get is:

```
hello.1
hello.10
hello.101
hello.11
hello.2
hello.20
etc.
```

How can I sort the file list so that it is numerically accurate?

Comment: Where do you expect the `.H` to end up?

Comment: @tink the .H should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't the leading text; it's that `sort` is sorting things lexicographically rather than numerically. Even without the prefix we see:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done | sort
1
10
100
11
12
.
.
.
```

If you want to sort things numerically by the extension, you need to (a) tell `sort` to sort numerically with `-n` and (b) tell `sort` which field to use with the `-k` and `-t` options:

```
find ./ -name 'hello*.[0-9]*' | sort -t. -k3 -n
```

Which produces:

```
./hello.1
./hello.2
./hello.3
./hello.4
./hello.5
./hello.6
./hello.7
./hello.8
./hello.9
./hello.10
.
.
.
./hello.100
.
.
.
./hello.199
./hello.200
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` you want is `sort -t. -k3n` where `-t` allows you to specify the separator character `'.'` and `-k` lets you specify the `KEYDEF` (how to sort) based on the 3rd field numeric. (due to specifying the leading `./` portion of the path also providing a `'.'` in the `find` output - thanks @larsks)

**Example**

With your sample files in the `files` directory, e.g.

```
$ tree files
files
├── hello.1
├── hello.10
├── hello.101
├── hello.11
├── hello.2
└── hello.20

0 directories, 6 files
```

Sorting with `-t. -k3n` would result in:

```
$ find ./files -name "hello.[0-9]*" | sort -t. -k3n
./files/hello.1
./files/hello.2
./files/hello.10
./files/hello.11
./files/hello.20
./files/hello.101
```

**NOTE**

When separating on fields with `'.'` how you specify the search path will influence whether or not a leading `./` is present. For example, search the subdirectory `files` without the `./` prefix would need to sort on the 2nd field, e.g.

```
$ find files -name "hello.[0-9]*" | sort -t. -k2n
files/hello.1
files/hello.2
files/hello.10
files/hello.11
files/hello.20
files/hello.101
```

Let me know if you have questions.

(another approach is an `awk` decorate and sort duplicating the last field `$NF` as your sort field)

**Using awk - Decorate and sort**

You can use `awk` to prefix (decorate) each line with the number from the last field separating on `'.'` and then remove the prefix after a numeric sort. This avoids counting fields, but does add two additional subshells (not an issue normally, e.g.)

```bash
find ./files -name "hello.[0-9]*" | awk -F. '{print $NF" "$0}' | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Example**

```
find ./files -name "hello.[0-9]*" | awk -F. '{print $NF" "$0}' | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
./files/hello.1
./files/hello.2
./files/hello.10
./files/hello.11
./files/hello.20
./files/hello.101
```

The benefit is how you prefix the search no longer makes any difference to the sort, e.g.

```
$ find files -name "hello.[0-9]*" | awk -F. '{print $NF" "$0}' | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
files/hello.1
files/hello.2
files/hello.10
files/hello.11
files/hello.20
files/hello.101
```

Comment: Note that `-t. -k2n` is wrong here, because the output of that `find` command in the question includes a leading `./` on every filename (so you need `-k3n`).

Comment: Ooh good catch -- will address.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect a result like:

```
hello.H
hello.1
hello.2
hello.10
hello.11
hello.20
hello.100
hello.101
hello.200
```

Why not just use:

```
find . -name "hello.[0-9]*"|sort -n -t. -k3
```

`-k3` along with `-t.` will sort the third column with column delimiter `.`

You can also experiment with sort variations, replacing `-n` for numeric sorting with any of the following:

- general-numeric -g
- human-numeric -h
- month -M
- numeric -n
- random -R
- version -V

Comment: Good approach, only drawback is whether a `'.'` is provided as part of the `path` option to `find` and whether there are any additional `'.'` contained in the path (I ran into the same issue...) Could end up being `-k2n`, `-k3n`, ...

Comment: The OP's question refers to `find ./` this my example. And I suggested with experimenting with k2/3 ... Also OPs question shows the PATTERN of filenames he is dealing with. Solution is not perfect, but is tailored to solving the Ops Question